# On active class heading color change ( add / remove class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on accordion here I have two content div blocks I got the output but the problem is my code is not in standard form and lines of code is more. I want to make it short and simple way just using add/remove class. And I want to change the active tab heading color. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

```js
$(".benefits-slide1").click(function() {
  if ($(".benefits-slideDiv1").hasClass("noDisplay")) {
    $(".benefits-slideDiv1").removeClass("noDisplay").show("slideDown");
    $(".benefits-slideDiv2, .benefits-slideDiv3, .benefits-slideDiv4").addClass("noDisplay").hide("slideDown");
  }
});

$(".benefits-slide2").click(function() {
  if ($(".benefits-slideDiv2").hasClass("noDisplay")) {
    $(".benefits-slideDiv2").removeClass("noDisplay").show("slideDown");
    $(".benefits-slideDiv1, .benefits-slideDiv3, .benefits-slideDiv4").addClass("noDisplay").hide("slideDown");
  }
});

$(".benefits-slide3").click(function() {
  if ($(".benefits-slideDiv3").hasClass("noDisplay")) {
    $(".benefits-slideDiv3").removeClass("noDisplay").show("slideDown");
    $(".benefits-slideDiv1, .benefits-slideDiv2, .benefits-slideDiv4").addClass("noDisplay").hide("slideDown");
  }
});

$(".benefits-slide4").click(function() {
  if ($(".benefits-slideDiv4").hasClass("noDisplay")) {
    $(".benefits-slideDiv4").removeClass("noDisplay").show("slideDown");
    $(".benefits-slideDiv1, .benefits-slideDiv2, .benefits-slideDiv3").addClass("noDisplay").hide("slideDown");
  }
});
```

```css
.slideDiv1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.slideDiv2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.slideDiv3 {
  background-color: green;
}

.slideDiv4 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.noDisplay {
  display: none;
}

div#accordionExample {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.benefits-wrap {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion nav" id="accordionExample" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <div class="benefits-acc">
    <button class="benefits d-flex benefits-slide1">
   <h3 class="pl-3">Personalized health journey</h3>
  </button>
    <div class="card-body benefits-slideDiv1">
      <p>content 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="benefits-acc">
  <button class="benefits d-flex benefits-slide2">
  <h3 class="pl-3">Personalized health journey</h3>
 </button>
  <div class="card-body benefits-slideDiv2 noDisplay">
    <p>content 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="benefits-acc">
  <button class="benefits d-flex benefits-slide3">
  <h3 class="pl-3">Personalized health journey</h3>
 </button>
  <div class="card-body benefits-slideDiv3 noDisplay">
    <p>content 3</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="benefits-acc">
  <button class="benefits d-flex benefits-slide4">
  <h3 class="pl-3">Personalized health journey</h3>
 </button>
  <div class="card-body benefits-slideDiv4 noDisplay">
    <p>content 4</p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>


<div class="benefits-wrap">
  <h3>Second content block</h3>
  <div class="benefits-slideDiv1"> Second content 1</div>
  <div class="benefits-slideDiv2 noDisplay">Second content 2</div>
  <div class="benefits-slideDiv3 noDisplay">Second content 3</div>
  <div class="benefits-slideDiv4 noDisplay">Second content 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example (not perfect) of what you've tried to do, note that I've used HTML5 `data-*` attribute in each button to store the *className* of the associated `div`'s.

```js
$(".benefits").click(function() {

  let otherButtons = $(".benefits").not($(this));
  otherButtons.siblings(".card-body").addClass("noDisplay");
  otherButtons.parent().removeClass("active");
  
  $(this).parent().addClass("active");

  $('.benefits-wrap').children('div').addClass("noDisplay");

  let divClass = $(this).data('div');
  
  $(`.${divClass}`).toggleClass("noDisplay");

});
```

```css
.benefits-slideDiv1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.benefits-slideDiv2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.benefits-slideDiv3 {
  background-color: green;
}

.benefits-slideDiv4 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.noDisplay {
  display: none;
}

div#accordionExample {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.benefits-wrap {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
}

.benefits-acc.active {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.benefits-acc.active h3 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion nav" id="accordionExample" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <div class="benefits-acc active">
    <button class="benefits d-flex benefits-slide1" data-div="benefits-slideDiv1">
   <h3 class="pl-3">Personalized health journey</h3>
  </button>
    <div class="card-body benefits-slideDiv1">
      <p>content 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="benefits-acc">
  <button class="benefits d-flex benefits-slide2" data-div="benefits-slideDiv2">
  <h3 class="pl-3">Personalized health journey</h3>
 </button>
  <div class="card-body benefits-slideDiv2 noDisplay">
    <p>content 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="benefits-acc">
  <button class="benefits d-flex benefits-slide3" data-div="benefits-slideDiv3">
  <h3 class="pl-3">Personalized health journey</h3>
 </button>
  <div class="card-body benefits-slideDiv3 noDisplay">
    <p>content 3</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="benefits-acc">
  <button class="benefits d-flex benefits-slide4" data-div="benefits-slideDiv4">
  <h3 class="pl-3">Personalized health journey</h3>
 </button>
  <div class="card-body benefits-slideDiv4 noDisplay">
    <p>content 4</p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>


<div class="benefits-wrap">
  <h3>Second content block</h3>
  <div class="benefits-slideDiv1"> Second content 1</div>
  <div class="benefits-slideDiv2 noDisplay">Second content 2</div>
  <div class="benefits-slideDiv3 noDisplay">Second content 3</div>
  <div class="benefits-slideDiv4 noDisplay">Second content 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Fractiion Awesome Can you change the heading color `personalized health journey` color on active

Comment: @Husna Check now

Comment: on Active tab I want to add background-color to `.benefits-acc` I had tried using add/ remove class not getting can you help me out this problem.`if(!$(".benefits-acc").children().hasClass("active")){
  $(this).children().find('.bbox').removeClass("bbox");
  $(this).children().addClass("bbox");
  alert('test');
  }else {
  $(this).children().removeClass("bbox");
  alert('test2');
  }`

Comment: I really appreciate you for giving time to solve the problem :).

Comment: ``$(`.${divClass}`).`` this grave accent ` symbol is not working in IE. Is there any other way to do.

Comment: Try with `$('.' + divClass)`

Comment: Yeah, I got it. thanks. Can you check this question how should i achieve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57691398/onclick-load-more-images-dynamically?noredirect=1#comment101827243_57691398